# Circle CI Docker Image: Php + Java

Tags: java, php, docker, circleci-2.0

I found separate Circle CI docker image for Php and Java.

```
- image: circleci/php:7.2.30
- image: circleci/openjdk:11.0.3-jdk-stretch
```

And I have run command to use 'java' command and it fails because it runs before jdk library.
Is there any circleci docker image with Php + Java?

or how to wait the 'run' command until docker image is ready?

Answer (score 0):

In order to "wait" you should use

```
wait-for: cobli/wait-for@x.x.x
```

as describd here:
https://circleci.com/developer/orbs/orb/cobli/wait-for